# Matching rows across tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am looking for a way to match rows b/w two tables.

```
name_tokens
-----------------
product_id, tokens
----------------
1, token 1
1, token 2
1, token 3
2, token 1
2, token 2
3, token 1
4, token 1

-----------
models_tokens
---------------
product_id, tokens
------------------
1, token 1
1, token 2
2, token 1
3, token 1
4, token 1
```

So basically one table contains the model tokens of a product and other one contains the name tokens of product. I want to get all those products whose name tokens contains all the model tokens.

It will go like this. 
1.) For each product see how much model token are there for a product
2.) Check name tokens for existence of for each model token of that product. If yes that counts a match.

I hope I made the scenerio clear. If not I would anything that is requested to the question.

**Edit**

```
---------
name_tokens
-----------------
product_id, tokens
----------------
1, hello
1, world
1, stackoverflow
2, Stack 
2, overflow
3, stack
4, flow

-----------
models_tokens
---------------
product_id, tokens
------------------
1, hello
1, stackoverflow
2, ovreflow
3, overflow
4, stack
```

So result I need is

```
product_id
1
2
```

Comment: in this case you want to get product id `1` from `name_tokens`?

Comment: @491243 I din't used token 1 to represent a value, It just to say first token goes there. So product id 1 in case token 1 and token 2 on both tables for that products has the same value. say token 1 is "hello" and token 2 is "world"

Comment: If still not clear please let me know. I'll update the example with some real data

Comment: just give your desired result.

Comment: I would appreciate the reason for negative mark, so that I can improve next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this with a left outer join and aggregation:

```
select nt.product_id
from name_tokens nt left outer join
     model_tokens mt
     on nt.product_id = mt.product_id and
        nt.tokens = mt.tokens
group by nt.product_id
having count(mt.product_id) = count(*);
```

What this query does is start with the `name_tokens` table and find all matches in the `model_tokens` table.  If there is no match, then `NULL` is assigned to the rows in `mt` (courtesy of the `left outer join`).  The `having` clause returns all products that have an equal number of matches in the second table as there are tokens in the first.

EDIT:

For the reverse, you can reverse the query:

```
select mt.product_id
from model_tokens mt  left outer join
     name_tokens nt
     on nt.product_id = mt.product_id and
        nt.tokens = mt.tokens
group by mt.product_id
having count(nt.product_id) = count(*);
```

Note that the `having` clause changes as well as the order of the joins and the `group by` clause.

Comment: HI @Gordon First of all thanks a lot for coming with answer. But this seems to work exact opposite of what i required. It returns the product whose all name tokens exists in model tokens. I need products whose all model token exist in name tokens.

Comment: I think I just need to switch table positioning. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: In the second solution should it be group by mt.product_id? or I am missing something?